# Data Structres Basic Program

Tags: c, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertion(int X,Node *l);
void display( Node *y);

void display(Node *y)
{
   printf("\n Your Node Contains \n Data : %d \t Pointer : %d \n ",y->data,y->sp);
}

void insertion(int X,Node *l)
{
   l->data=X;
   l->sp=NULL;
}

typedef struct 
{
   int data;
   int *sp;
}Node;

int main(void)
{
   int kl; Node *j;
   printf("\n Enter the data you like to put :");
   scanf("%d",&kl);
   insertion(kl,j);
   display(j);
   return 0;
}
```

There are errors during compilation - "Unknown Type Node "on Line 3,4,5,9. Why ?
I am unable to rectify the Mistakes.i have only recently started data structures and this was just one node Data insertion Program.

Comment: `typedef` define first.

Comment: Did you notice that it *didn't* complain about the uses of `Node` on lines 19 and 22?

Comment: Yea. That's what i am wondering.

Comment: Types must be declared before use.

Comment: How should i do that ? in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is pretty simple, you have to typedef your struct before you try to use it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct // You cant use the Node keyword before this
{
    int data;
    int *sp;
}Node;

void insertion(int X,Node *l);
void display( Node *y);

void display(Node *y)
{
    printf("\n Your Node Contains \n Data : %d \t Pointer : %d \n ",y->data,y->sp);
}

void insertion(int X,Node *l)
{
    l->data=X;
    l->sp=NULL;
}


int main(void)
{
    int kl; Node *j;
    printf("\n Enter the data you like to put :");
    scanf("%d",&kl);
    insertion(kl,j);
    display(j);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler tries to compile the line

```
void insertion(int X,Node *l);
```

it does not know anything about `Node`. You have to move the declaration of `Node` before that line.

Move the lines

```
typedef struct 
{
   int data;
   int *sp;
}Node;
```

before that line.

Comment: But then? Compilation starts from Main Program . Isn't it .

Comment: @Avan, compilation starts from the first line of the file. When the program is executed, it starts execution from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node *j as linked list type then you need to allocate memory to it, then only you can assign any value to it. Otherwise it is just a pointer which points to some other variable.

Answer (score 0):

### First specify The Node Using Structure

First and foremost rule of using data structure is to ***define the data structure*** at the top of you program.Then only you can use it anywhere in your program.A sample program as follows:

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
struct *node{
           int data;
            node *link;}top;             //top object created
```

Follow this method to minimize the error in your code